# How to get JSON data into HTML for drawing a multiple rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to draw a rectangle box in HTML using JSON data which I will get.
Right now the problem is that from my JSON file it's taking single object data only not for all the object which i have mention in JSON file.

JSON file :

```
var data = [
{
    "Frame_count":1,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":2,

        output:{

            "x_val":82.98839,
            "y_val":197.5625,
            "width":316.03088,
            "height":197.45447,

        }

        {
            "x_val":522.48224,
            "y_val":170.47296,
            "width":64.66699,
            "height":61.7807,

        },

},
{
    "Frame_count":2,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":2,

        output:{

            "x_val":78.99908,
            "y_val":189.48056,
            "width":327.41034,
            "height":198.80237,

        }

        {
            "x_val":506.4537,
            "y_val":170.87192,
            "width":67.57986,
            "height":52.28564,

        },

},
{
    "Frame_count":3,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":2,

        output:{

            "x_val":96.17151,
            "y_val":187.14635,
            "width":316.49564,
            "height":202.9623,

        }

        {
            "x_val":510.68835,
            "y_val":173.45544,
            "width":67.07324,
            "height":51.9642,

        },

},
{
    "Frame_count":4,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":2,

        output:{

            "x_val":138.38567,
            "y_val":188.03767,
            "width":295.46558,
            "height":186.23979,

        }

        {
            "x_val":517.48627,
            "y_val":164.86668,
            "width":65.31262,
            "height":65.73456,

        },

},
{
    "Frame_count":5,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":1,

        output:{

            "x_val":158.95529,
            "y_val":185.81998,
            "width":261.55298,
            "height":190.83698,

        },

},
{
    "Frame_count":6,

        "Objects_detected":1,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":2,

        output:{

            "x_val":165.79619,
            "y_val":197.32138,
            "width":258.42517,
            "height":173.56177,

        }

        {
            "x_val":518.94965,
            "y_val":165.03098,
            "width":60.58582,
            "height":64.88766,

        },

},

{
    "Frame_count":7,

        "Objects_detected":2,
        "Objects_classname":"car",
        "Number_of_class_object":1,

        output:{

            "x_val":309.74548,
            "y_val":195.05283,
            "width":184.09943,
            "height":115.93958,

        },


        "Objects_classname":"person",
        "Number_of_class_object":1,

        output:{

            "x_val":257.47906,
            "y_val":206.84875,
            "width":41.11475,
            "height":83.16348,

        },

}
]
```

Here you see that in above JSON file it's taking data and drawing a rectangle of only one object.

check the frame_count : 1 in JSON file: for this my code has to draw two rectangle box based on the x,y,width and height data of JSON file.

my code :

```
window.setInterval(ctx1.rect(local_data[j].output.x_val, local_data[j].output.y_val, local_data[j].output.width, local_data[j].output.height), 90);
ctx1.fillText(data[j].Objects_classname, local_data[j].output.x_val + 5, local_data[j].output.y_val - 10);

ctx1.stroke();
ctx1.beginPath();
```

Comment: First of all, your json is not valid. And what do you want to achieve? I can see some object contains two output and some contains two object within output.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid json. You may want to look at arrays by using [] in json

Comment: @Abhishek I have no idea of JSON file. But Is it possible for you to reformat it in such way like when frame 1 comes it has to draw two rectangle boxes simultaneously whatever the data we get from JSON file.

Comment: Is this one is valid format of JSON `var data = [
{
 "Frame_count":1,
 
  "Objects_detected":2,
  "Objects_classname":"car",
  "output": {
  "1": {"x_val":82.9883,"y_val":197.56245,"width":316.03088,"height":197.45451},
  "2":{"x_val":522.4823,"y_val":170.47263,"width":64.66687,"height":61.78085}}


  "Total_objects_detected":2,
}`

Comment: I got the valid JSON file thanks

Comment: one more question how can i get array of array data simultaneously.  JSON file : `var data = [
{
 "Frame_count":1,
 
  "Objects_detected":2,
  "Objects_classname":"car",
  
  output : [
  {
   "x_val":82.9883,
   "y_val":197.56245,
   "width":316.03088,
   "height":197.45451
  },
   
  {
   "x_val":522.4823,
   "y_val":170.47263,
   "width":64.66687,
   "height":61.78085
  }
  ],
 

  "Total_objects_detected":2,
}]`   here I wanted to fetch two array's (value of output) data in a one shot. If it is possible please help me

Comment: please don't give down vote it will not help for new comers. Just let me know what is a problem and I will try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my code, I am able to read the data from JSON file and it will draw a multiple rectangle.

code :

```
if (data[i].Total_objects_detected > 0) {
                                             var objectsDetected = data[i].Total_objects_detected;
                                             $(".content").empty(); //overwrite the JSON data
                                             $(".content").append(getTemplate(i, frameCount, objectsDetected));
                                            for (var z = 0; z < objectsDetected;z++){                                            
                                             if (data[i].output[z].Objects_classname) {
                                             var objectsClassname = data[i].output[z].Objects_classname;
                                             }
                                             if (data[i].output[z].x_val) {
                                             var x = data[i].output[z].x_val;
                                             }
                                             if (data[i].output[z].y_val) {
                                             var y = data[i].output[z].y_val;
                                             }
                                             if (data[i].output[z].width) {
                                             var width = data[i].output[z].width;
                                             }
                                             if (data[i].output[z].height) {
                                             var height = data[i].output[z].height;
                                             }
                                            $(".wrapper#" + i).find(".subWrapper").append(getSubTemplate(objectsClassname, x, y, width, height));

                                             } 
                     }
                      else {
                                $(".content").append(getTemplate(i, frameCount, 0));
                           }
```